# Saving pointers of derived class to a vector of "base class pointer"

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I need to save my pointers of derived classes in a vector of pointer to a baseclass

PKW and Fahrrad are derived classes of Fahrzeug.

```
    unique_ptr<PKW> teslatruck =
    make_unique<PKW>(34,"Tesla Truck",100,30,120);

    unique_ptr<Fahrrad> fahrrad =
        make_unique<Fahrrad>(13,"Fahrrad",30);


    vector<unique_ptr<Fahrzeug>> aufgabe2vector;
    aufgabe2vector.push_back(move(teslatruck));
    aufgabe2vector.push_back(move(fahrrad));
```

How can I solve my problem?

This is the error I get:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void push_back(const std::__1::unique_ptr<Fahrzeug,std::__1::default_delete<Fahrzeug>> &)
void push_back(std::__1::unique_ptr<Fahrzeug,std::__1::default_delete<Fahrzeug>> &&)
```

Comment: First of all please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it, together with the full and complete copy-paste (as text) of the build log.

Comment: you have to post the `Fahrzeug` and other classes. The error [is not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/vTMo9h59b).

Comment: To explain the problem (without having a good duplicate reference, which I'm sure already exists): While `PKW` is a class derived from  `Fahrzeug`, `std::unique_ptr<PKW>` is not a class derived from `std::unique_ptr<Fahrzeug>`, and for some strange reason automatic conversion doesn't hit.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] use this as starting point https://godbolt.org/z/zvTd3Gzqd I suspect that `Fahrzeug` is not inherited publicly by `PKW` and `Fahrrad`. Also I would recommend to write code in English only. It is better to see `Bicycle` instead `Fahrrad`.

Comment: My random guess is the inheritance is accidentally `private` because no access specifier was provided and the types are classes.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It is publicly inherited, and also the thing is that the code is working although the lines are underlined with red.

Comment: @MarekR it is my first question here in stackoverflow I will try my best and edit it later , also it is my project in my German university so class names were pre defined given

Comment: @Aleksan If the code compiles and run, but the IDE is highlighting an error, most likely a cache is out of date or your IDE is failing to parse your code correctly. In that case, this isn't a C++ question, it is a question about whichever IDE you are using.